# android studio design view too small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I find the Android Studio (v1.0.1) layout "Design" view to be too small to be useful - I can barely see some of the elements. The "zoom" button shows only a very small portion of the layout. Is there a way to detach the view so that I can enlarge it?

And is Android Studio's "Design" view different from the "Preview pane" that I see referenced in various forums?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you program, but I much more prefer the text mode with a preview.

There are 2 modes for the xml:

1. Text
   [image]
2. Design
   [image]

While in Text mode you can:

- Enable the preview
  [image]
- Turn it into a floating-resizable window:
  [image]

Comment: Ah, I just found the "preview" icon - thanks! How do I turn the preview pane into a free floating window?

Comment: @Tomasso it's a vertical button on the right side of AndroidStudio. You can see it clicked in the screenshots.

Comment: Thanks - how do I turn the pane into a free-floating window?

Comment: @Tomasso click the wheel icon at the top of the preview window.

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide the bars on the sides and the bottom for example. Simply click on the according category, which always has a number in front (e.g. `1:Project` on the left, or `4:Run` at the bottom).

Alternatively, you can double-click on the tab of your design view, which will resize it to full-screen.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to separate the tab to be in a separate window.  However, if you zoom in the designer you can then pan around the visualization using the scroll bars.  If you want to see the "preview" then at the bottom of the pane, look for the "text" tab.  Select that instead of "design" and you'll be taken to the raw text XML.  While in text edit mode, you can see a live preview of the layout.  It may be collapsed by default, look for "preview" on the right side of the overall window.